# How to check If datatable contains anyrow

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to check IF datatable contains anyrow ,I am using below code to do this ,But now even if this `GetReferralDrName()` method does not return any value still control is going to `foreach` loop ,what is the right way to do this

```
DataTable dt = DBHandling.GetReferralDrName();
            if (dt != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    cmbReferralDr.Items.Add(dr["LastName"].ToString() + " " + dr["FirstName"].ToString());
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no rows, there is no harm in getting to the foreach step. As it will just jump over that when there are no records in the datatable. But you could do this:

```
DataTable dt = DBHandling.GetReferralDrName();
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        cmbReferralDr.Items.Add(dr["LastName"].ToString() + " " + dr["FirstName"].ToString());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem.So try to check `dt.Rows.Count`.

```
if(dt!=null)
{
  if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
  {
    //Your Other Code
  }
}
```